# MVC controller not getting correct param value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Having issues with MVC binding or something.  In my action method, the id parameter is ALWAYS 3.  I even rebooted to make sure something wasn't cached.  Hoping I'm missing something simple here.  (I can't post the image of the debug session, since I have no reputation points.)  Any help would be great.

My controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSampleData(int id)
{
   return new JsonResult 
   { 
      Data = new List<string>{"some", "data", },
      JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
   };
}
```

From fiddler:
`GET http://localhost:51610/Event/GetSampleData/?id=50`

The link was generated with a jQuery call:

```
 $.ajax(url,
        {
            data: { id: 50 }
        }
 );
```

Comment: I am not sure where the 3 is coming from,  by default the id is part of the route.  In our links we have GetSampleData/50 instead of it being a query parameter.  how are you creating the link?

Comment: Matt, I added the jQuery code that generated the link.

Comment: Where are you calling this `$.ajax` function? Is it inside the `.click` event of some anchor or submit button? Or inside the `.submit` event of some form?

Comment: It indeed behaves when I just have /50 instead of /?id=50.

Comment: So now the question is what is the syntax to get it to GetSampleData/50?  If I have just data: 50 all fiddler shows is GetSampleData/

Comment: What's the value of the `url` javascript variable? Does it end with `GetSampleData/`? If so you should get rid of the trailing `/`.

Comment: Is there any route where id value is 3 ?

Comment: Hi Darin, I removed the trailing slash and the id is still 3.  I was hoping that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the url in the ajax call

```
$.ajax{
    url: '@Url.Action("GetSampleData", "Controller", new { id = "----" })".replace("----", 50),
    type...
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm this calling from another project/solution, that is just an html page.

Comment: ok, if I had to guess since you are using id it is conflicting with the route.  Try changing your id variable to GetSampleID on the view and on the controller